# Unable to merge dex after adding a third party .aar file

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-multidex

I am running into the `unable to merge dex` problem that many posts seem to complain about. After doing some research, I think I have found the source of the problem, but I don't know how to proceed to fix it.

I am currently putting together various third-party components to create an Android application. It consists of the following parts:

- `app`: The app itself, which is a minimal app with a Kotlin Activity created from Android Studio
- `libs`: Two .aar files, A.aar and B.aar, where A.aar depends on B.aar
- `base`: A third-party java module which provides some interfaces, helper functions and includes some dependencies for them. This module has its own build.gradle file.

I integrated them following these steps:

- If I add `base` as a dependency of `app`, everything builds
- When I add A.aar as a dependency in the app's build.gradle, it still builds
- Then, when I add B.aar as a dependency for the app (`implementation B.aar`), the gradle build fails with the error: `Unable to merge dex`.

Looking at the Gradle stack trace, I found that it is complaining that multiple dex files define `Lcom.google.common.io.ByteSink`, which appears to be Google's Guava library.

Using the Project view in Android Studio, B.aar appears to actually *contain* version 18.0 of Guava inside it (under a 'classes.jar' section). I think this conflicts with `base`'s `implementation` dependency line for guava 20.0 in its build.gradle.

Thus, I think I have found the source of the conflict (2 different versions of guava colliding), but I am not sure how to proceed. Was the third party wrong to have packaged guava into the .aar? If so, do I have any means of working around this problem other than asking the third party to remove it?

Things we have tried and did not work:

- using `exclude` statements in the `implementation` statement that includes the AAR (I suspect it may only work with external dependencies, not with code that is built into the AAR)
- using `preDexLibraries` (`true` worked for some of us, `false` worked for others -- it's not a solution!)

I'm more of a C++/C guy, so I may need a bit of hand holding with Java-specific concepts. I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Not sure, maybe `implementation('B.aar', { exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava' })`

Comment: Thanks @dewey, yeah I already tried that too but it didn't work. I'm starting to wonder if there's a way to repackage the aar such that guava is removed. I'm not really supposed to change it, but if I can prove that removing it helps, perhaps I can convince the 3rd party...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution we found was to do the following to the third party AAR:

- Open the AAR file with a .zip file editor (ex: 7-zip)
- Open classes.jar within the AAR
- Navigate to the `com` directory
- Delete the `google` subdirectory

We then added guava as a dependency in the gradle file
It works, it's the right thing to do, and we are pending an ok from our third-party provider.

Comment: Update: The 3rd party provider confirmed that they should not have packaged guava into their own code.